# Is `CLUSTER` applied by `pg_dump`?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

If [`CLUSTER` is set on a table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-cluster.html), then is it applied by `pg_dump`?

Specifically, the following:

1. Is it used to order the rows in the dump? If not, is there a way to do this?
2. Is it set on the table when using `pg_restore`? If not, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The dump will contain the statement

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CLUSTER ON anindex;
```

Restoring the dump will execute that statement. As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) explains,

> This form selects the default index for future `CLUSTER` operations. It does not actually re-cluster the table.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any way to "apply" this on dump or restore?

Comment: No. You will have to run `CLUSTER` after restoring.